# Excel VBA: get content from online HTML table

Tags: html, excel, vba, dom

can anybody pleas show me part of VBA code, which will get text "hello" from this example online HTML table? first node will be found by his ID (id="something").

```
...
<table id="something">
  <tr>
    <td><TABLE><TR><TD></TD></TR><TR><TD></TD></TR></TABLE></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td>hello</td>
  </tr>
...
```

i think it will be something like `child->sibling->child->sibling->sibling->child`, but I don't know the exact way.

**EDIT**
updated code tags are CAPITALS. so if I use `getElemenetsById("something").getElemenetsByTagName('tr')` it get only two tr tags to collection, or four (with tags which are deeper children)?

Comment: why minus 1 ? I think it's simple and clear question for anybody who work with this.

Comment: Im certain this exact question has been asked before, pretty sure I commented or gave an answer too.. Just cant find it

Comment: @NickSlash firstly. ok, if you gave an answer, you can see it in your profile, I think. secondly, before I asked, I tried to find answer by check links generated by input where you writing question. nothing relevant has been found. so I dont undestand, why minus 1, is it so hard to write answer, if you know it?

Comment: I didn't -1 your question.

Comment: @NickSlash At first sight it seemed. I apologize

Answer (score 5):

If you did search for an answer, you might want to broaden your scope next time. There are plenty of questions and answers that deal with DOM stuff and VBA.

[Use getElementById on HTMLElement instead of HTMLDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15191847/212869)

While the question (and answers) aren't **exactly** what you want, it will show you how to create something you can work with.

You'll need to use a mixture of `getElementById()` and `getElemenetsByTagName()` to retrieve your desired "hello"

eg: `Document.getElementById("something").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText`

- Get the element "something"
- Inside "something" get all "tr" tags (specifically the one at index 1)
- Inside the returned tr tag get all "td" tags (specifically the one at index 2)
- Get the innerText of the previous result

These objects use a 0 based array so the first item is item(0).

**Update**

`document.getElementById()` will return **an** (singular) IHTMLElement (which will include all of its children) or nothing/null if it does not exist.

`document.getElementsByTagName()` will return a **collection** of IHTMLElement (again, each element will include all of its children). (or an empty collection if none exist)

`document.getElementsByTagName("tr")` this will return all tr elements inside the "document" element.

`document.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)` will return the **first** (singular) IHTMLElement from the collection. (note the index at the end?)

There is no (that i could find) "sibling" feature of the InternetExplorer object in VBA, so you'd have to do it manually using the child index.

Using the DOM Functions **is** the clean way to do it. Its much clearer than just looking at a chain "Element.Children(0).children(1).children(2)" as you've no idea what the index means without manually looking it up.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try, but I think there must be straighter way, how to get elements in DOM tree. something like in other stackowerflow question that you send (Element.Children(1).Children(0).innerText).  And in this example I can't see something like "`getElementsByTagName("td")(2)`", so if I find it, I still would not know answer.

Comment: The answer to the question used something like that and the IHTMLElement object  does support the children property. Go read the documentation on the MSDN. A for a straighter way, I'm not sure what you mean.there it's no magic short hand way to do it.

Comment: so I tried. problem is, that table cell <td> can include whole new table. so if I use `getElementById("something").getElementsByTagName("tr")(2)` it collect all TRs under "something" element (right?). so than I will get first row from table contained in first row of base table. thats why I'm asking about clean way like children->sibling...

Comment: I wrote it little bit puzzled, sorry. this sentence  _it collect all TRs under "something" element (right?)_ should sounds like _it collect all TRs under "something" element including these in the nested table and chose third of them (right?)_. I updated example in my question, so now it describes the situation better. maybe :-) The nested table is why I'm looking for sibling feature (if its working like in my updated question)

Comment: Yes it will get all the tr elements from your nested tables. Again, I don't believe the VBA implementation includes Sibling and next child etc. You'll have to loop over the result of your `getElementsByTagName` and make sure its parent node is the top level table.

Answer (score 1):

I looked all over for the answer to this question, too.  I finally found the solution by talking to a coworker which was actually through recording a macro.

I know, you all think you are above this, but it is actually the best way.  See the full post here: http://automatic-office.com/?p=344
In short, you want to record the macro and go to data --> from web and navigate to your website and select the table you want.

I have used the above solutions "get element by id" type stuff in the past, and it is great for a few elements, but if you want a whole table, and you aren't super experienced, just record a macro.
don't tell your friends and then reformat it to look like your own work so no one knows you used the macro tool ;)

Comment: thanks for comment. I have been looking for some more programming way like child/sibling. but it's good to know other solution

Comment: It is actually highly efficient too, so I don't think you are going to come up with anything better.