# Get HTML Element index number?

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to write something that pulls the `.innerText` from an HTML element.  Here's my applicable code:

```
Sub test()
Dim URL = "https:// ** the website **"
Dim TDelements As IHTMLElementCollection, TDElementsRef As IHTMLElementCollection
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Navigate URL
    .Visible = True

    ' Wait for the page to load
    While .Busy Or .READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Set HTMLdoc = .Document
End With

Set TDelements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("td")
Set TDElementsRef = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("tdData")

r = 0

For Each TDelement In TDElementsRef
    If bGetNext Then
        Range("A1").Offset(r - 1, 1).Value = TDelement.innerText
        bGetNext = False
    End If
    Debug.Print TDelement.innerText
    If TDelement.className = "tdTitle" Then
        If TDelement Then
            Range("A1").Offset(r + 1, 0).Value = TDelement(2).innerText
            bGetNext = True 'Trigger to get the information from the next TDelement
            r = r + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
End sub
```

This will loop through all the info in between the `<td>` tags in the HTML.  How though, do I ask VB what INDEX I'm currently at? I tried doing (just after the two `Debug.Print` lines) `Debug.Print TDelement.Index` but of course that's not right.  How do I get the index of each TDelement??

The HTML looks like this:

[image]

and I just need to get the info in Green.

Comment: Use a counter to count up as you go through the loop.  HTML doesn't have an "Index" concept.  Code looks odd though - you're getting all td's with class name "tdData", but within the loop you're checking for className "tdTitle" - that should never be true (from your sample HTML).

Comment: I thought it did? Say I use the counter and find that the info I want happens when `i = 3`.  Instead of writing an If statement to check, I thought you could do something like `Document.getElementByClassName("tdData")(3)` which would only pull the third one?  (Perhaps that's not called "index", sorry for my lack of technical jargon with the HTML stuff :P).

Comment: (Note: I am trying to learn and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141394/excel-vba-get-content-from-online-html-table) page, which is where my thinking comes from).

Comment: `Document.getElementByClassName("tdData")(3)` Yes, you can do this (though that index starts at zero so that would give you the *fourth* element)  I just meant that HTML document elements don't have a direct `Index` property

Comment: What is the `type` for the `Document.getElementByClassName("tdData")(3)`?  Because when I use that for `Set TDelementsRef = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("tdData")(3)`, I get a "Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch".  What would I need to change, so that `TDelementsRef` gets set to `123456789`?

Comment: You've declared `TDelementsRef` as a Collection, but you're trying to set it to a single element.  If you only want to get the value of the td then `Document.getElementByClassName("tdData")(3).innerText` should give you that

Comment: Aha! That works (note I also had to change `TDElementsRef` to a `String`).  Thanks so much @TimWilliams! (if you put that as an answer, I'll mark as such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `TDelementsRef` as a Collection, but you're trying to set it to a single element.

If you only want to get the value of a single specific td element then:

```
Dim tdVal as String
tdVal = Document.getElementByClassName("tdData")(3).innerText
```

should do what you need.