# Internet Explorer VBA - Retrieve text from Class but have dynamic starting point?

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am working on an Excel VBA project to extract some information from a webpage and bring it into an Excel wrokbook. This is a screenshot of the webpage I am working with:

[image: sample]

What I am looking to do is extract text based on two criteria: Name and post date. For example, I have the name Kaelan and the post date of 11/16/2016. I want to extract the amount of $365.

This is an example of the HTML code:

```htm
<td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnPostDate tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnPostDate_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
   <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnPostDateCell">
      <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">11/16/2016</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
<td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAmount tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAmount_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
   <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnAmountCell">
      <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">$ 365.00</div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</td>
```

The names are ID's in the HTML that are unique and I am able to extract them. The rest of the information (post date, effective date, quantity, and amount) all have the same class name in the entire table: `divListTableBodyLabel`.

Now I know I can use `ie.document.getElementsByClassName("divListTableBodyLabel")` and whatever number at the end to pick out the nth instance of that class. The problem is that n is dynamic in my case. Is there a way that I can search for the date (11/16/2016) and then use that as my starting point to move (2) 3 spots over to retrieve the amount of $365?

Is there a way I can limit my extract/search only to a portion of the HTML below the name Kaelan?

I am working my way through learning HTML and VBA, but I wanted to know if what I am seeking to is even possible or if there might be a better way to tackle the problem?

*EDIT*

This is the HTML code that lies above the code I posted previously:

```htm
<div class="familyLedgerAmountCategory" id="id_4541278">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdCategoryRow">
                <div class="cmFloatLeft divExpandToggle expanded" id="divCategoryToggle_id_4541278"></div>
                <div class="cmFloatLeft" id="divCategoryLabel_id_4541278" style="width: 430px;">
                    Kaelan
                </div><span style="margin-left: 5px;">$ 465.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="trListTableBody LedgerExisting" id="CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
                <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnDescription tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnDescription_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
                    <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnDescriptionCell">
                        <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                                        <a class="aColumnDescriptionCell" id="aColumnDescriptionCell_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465" name="aColumnDescriptionCell_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465" target="_self" title="Click to view details">2017 Super Early Bird Teen Camp - Tuition</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnPostDate tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnPostDate_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
                    <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnPostDateCell">
                        <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                                        11/16/2016
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnEffective tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnEffective_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
                    <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnEffectiveCell">
                        <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                                        11/15/2016
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnQty tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnQty_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
                    <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnQtyCell">
                        <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                                        1
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAmount tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAmount_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
                    <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnAmountCell">
                        <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                                        $ 365.00
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAction tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAction_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So I know I can go up the chain to extract specific items, but the problem in this situation is that each row of the table has a unique ID: `id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnPostDate_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465` that I have no way to know what it is. It's a sequential number that runs across the site based on posting date from what I've looked at so there's no way for me to know exactly what that number is. I know the ID for a name such as Kaelan, but below that in the HTML code is an ID for each row that I have no way of knowing. This is the reason that I feel like I have to have a dynamic starting point unless there's another way to think/tackle this problem?

Comment: Technically, the HTML document is a string. To extract an element from it, by whatever method, simply looks for a string within that string, such as a class name, finds the end of that element and returns another string. You can build your own function if the built-in one doesn't work for you. You can use the Instr() function to search for "11/16/2016" in the entire HTMLDocument or any part of it. Once you find it you can write code to extract the element in which it was found and find your way from there to the amount you want to extract.

Comment: they are descendants of a unique tag `<div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumn...` , so work from that tag

Comment: check here ... answer by NickSlash ... it may help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141394/excel-vba-get-content-from-online-html-table#16145802

Comment: Maybe you didnt show all the HTML from Kalean down to the 365 ( and enclosing HTML. I think you need to go to the parent element of what you showed and then analyse from there. Get Kalean and all the HTML that pertains to the data for Kalean, and then you have an easy job

Comment: When you get the root for Kalean, you can call `rootElement.getElementsByClassName("divListTableBodyLabel")`, and you will get a collection which should be the various lables such as 11/16/2016, $ 365 etc

Comment: @MacroMarc I have added a fuller picture of the HTML code to the original post. As explained above, there is an unknown piece (an ID for each row) that lies between the known (Kaelan) and the information I want to extract (amount based on post date). This is the reason that I believe that I need a dynamic start point, but again I'm pretty new to all this so there could be another way that I am unaware of.

Comment: Get the collection of `<div class="cmFloatLeft>`, and then test each one's innerText for Kaelan. Then hook back to the relevant TR. I can't read that for you as it is jumbled

Comment: @MacroMarc So I believe this code will cycle through the cmFloatLeft class. Then once I have that element, then I can I try to get the details for "divListTableBodyLabel" for the matching cmFloatLeft of "Kaelan"? I get an error on this code since I'm assuming you can't just take one class and then try to get the class below it? `For Each oElement In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("cmFloatLeft")
      If oElement.innerText = "Kaelan" Then
        extract1 = oElement.getElementsByClassName("divListTableBodyLabel").innerText
        MsgBox extract1
      Else
      End If
    Next`