# Web Scraping with Internet Explorer VBA - Get data from an unknown variable?

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am working on an Excel VBA project to scrape some specific information from a website. The view of this data on the website is as such:

[Website View:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukVGe.png)

What I am looking to do is extract text based on two criteria: Name and post date. For example, I have the name Kaelan and the post date of 11/16/2016. I want to extract the amount of $365.

This is the HTML code:

```htm
<div class="familyLedgerAmountCategory" id="id_4541278">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdCategoryRow">
        <div class="cmFloatLeft divExpandToggle expanded" id="divCategoryToggle_id_4541278"></div>
        <div class="cmFloatLeft" id="divCategoryLabel_id_4541278" style="width: 430px;">
          Kaelan
        </div><span style="margin-left: 5px;">$ 465.00</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="trListTableBody LedgerExisting" id="CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
        <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnDescription tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnDescription_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
          <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnDescriptionCell">
            <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                    <a class="aColumnDescriptionCell" id="aColumnDescriptionCell_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465" name="aColumnDescriptionCell_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465" target="_self" title="Click to view details">2017 Super Early Bird Teen Camp - Tuition</a>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnPostDate tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnPostDate_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
          <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnPostDateCell">
            <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                    11/16/2016
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnEffective tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnEffective_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
          <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnEffectiveCell">
            <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                    11/15/2016
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnQty tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnQty_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
          <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnQtyCell">
            <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                    1
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAmount tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAmount_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465">
          <div class="divListTableBodyCell" id="tdColumnAmountCell">
            <table class="tblListTableBodyCell">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="divListTableBodyLabel">
                    $ 365.00
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAction tdBorderTop" id="tdCamperFamilyLedgerTableColumnAction_CamperFamilyLedgerRowControl_14816465"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

My attempt to pull the amount is as follows:

```
Sub Test()
Dim ie As Object
Dim oElement As Object
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim NewWB As Workbook

Set NewWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsTarget = NewWB.Sheets(1)
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate website...
        Wait 6
    ie.document.All.Item("txtUserName").Value = "User"
    ie.document.All.Item("pswdPassword").Value = "Pass
    Wait 1
    ie.document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click
        Wait 5
       ie.navigate website...

    i = 1
    For Each oElement In ie.document.getElementsByClassName("cmFloatLeft") 
        If oElement.innerText = "Kaelan" Then 
            extract1 = oElement.getElementsByClassName("divListTableBodyLabel").inn‌​erText
            MsgBox extract1 
        Else 
        End If 
    Next
```

However, I get an error when running the code above. Can I get the class for cmFloatLeft that I am looking for and then try to call the divLisTableBodyLabel class immediately even though that class does not fall directly below the cmFloatLeft class?

Sorry, I'm still pretty new to scraping web data.

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @TimWilliams I receive an "Object does not support this property or method" on the "extract 1 =" line

Comment: You are looking inside `oElement` for other elements with class `divListTableBodyLabel`, but the div containing "Kaelen" has no child nodes.  You also need to show exactly how you're declaring your variables.

Comment: I always thought webscrapping in VBA is like art.

Comment: @TimWilliams I've edited the original post to include all the code. But that's what I thought might be the issue. So there is no way I can really connect the div containing "Kaelan" with the code below it? Because there is a "Row Control ID" with a completely random number that I would have no way of knowing since I checked similar pages and it seems like it's a sequential number running across the whole site. Could I then somehow search for the text Kaelan and use that as a starting point to then search for the post date of 11/16/2016 below it? And then again for the amount?

Comment: Could you post the link of that site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer VBA - Retrieve text from Class but have dynamic starting point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260135/internet-explorer-vba-retrieve-text-from-class-but-have-dynamic-starting-point)

Comment: A link would have helped answer this.

Answer (score 0):

That structure is a bit difficult to scrape - you could try going "up" from the "Kaelan" node to the patent table, and then looping over that to extract the various pieces of information.  If the post structures are consistent then that could provide one approach.

```
Set doc = IE.document
Set els = doc.getElementsByClassName("cmFloatLeft")
i = 1
For Each oElement In els
    Debug.Print oElement.innerText
    If Trim(oElement.innerText) = "Kaelan" Then
        Set tbl = GetParent(oElement, "table") '<< find the parent table
        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            'loop over the parent table
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                For Each cl In rw.Cells
                    Debug.Print cl.innerText
                Next cl
            Next rw
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Function to find a named parent (by tag name):

```
Function GetParent(el, tagParent)
    Dim rv As Object
    Set rv = el
    Do While Not rv.parentElement Is Nothing
        Set rv = rv.parentElement
        If UCase(rv.tagName) = UCase(tagParent) Then
            Set GetParent = rv
            Exit Function
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetParent = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: That code is definitely getting somewhere. It returns the headers of the table "Description, Post Date, Effective, Qty, Amount." It would need to go one level lower. Is that possible though since it seems like what it returned is on the same level as the name "Kaelan"?