# VBA automation to upload data into Salesforce

Tags: excel, vba, salesforce

The question is: is there any way to bind Excel with Salesforce and upload data?
What I am looking for is a code to manipulate Salesforce from excel, that is, click a specified button (New Case), fill in specified fields with information from Excel cells and finally click another button (Save).
Salesforce is opened from Internet Explorer. Does it mean it can be manipulated like IE object? If so, are they methods to navigate through specific fields on the screen?

Any directions very appreciated.

Comment: Never used Salesforce, but if it is a web app then it will be possible to automate it using VBA. How easy depends on what you want to do and how salesforce works. VBA has the same sort of DOM tools as Javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15191847/212869

Comment: A quick search brings on this [Force.com_Excel_Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Excel_Connector) . Or you are interested in developing one ? I wouldn't go with page scraping but rather calling Salesforce API.

Comment: Does anyone have any code that attaches to already running instance of IE and manipulates it? I have been searching here and there and found codes that open a new instance of IE. Those who were supposed to navigate already open instance of IE does not work. Error usually pops up on shell object.

Answer (score 0):

Good example of how to connect to already running instance of IE is this:

```html
Sub connectIE()
    Dim sWindows As New ShellWindows
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    
    For Each IE In sWindows
        IE.navigate ("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
        'you can put whatever you want to do with IE here
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
    

  
    Next
    
    
End Sub
```

please note you have to check the following items in menu>Tools>References:

'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' and 'Microsoft Internet Controls'