# Vba create collection with HTML elements

Tags: html, vba, collections, element

I am trying to catch web data using VBA.

I have such HTML lines:

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table class="mega-table">
    <thead>
       <tr>…</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>…</tr>
       <tr>…</tr>
       <tr>…</tr>
       <tr>…</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How can I create a collection for "tbody"? (Later I want to loop through all the elements it contains (all the "tr")).

Comment: I have been trying with .getElementsBy...but as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191847/use-getelementbyid-on-htmlelement-instead-of-htmldocument | in vba we cannot write: Document.getElementById("target").getElementsByTagName("tr").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for what you are after. Basically you want to select the element that contains the table, then select all the TRs of that table.

Updated to include selecting the table body as well.

```
 dim Elements as Object

 Set Elements = Browser.Document.getElementsByClassName("mega-table")(0).getElementsByTag‌​Name("tbody")‌(0).getElementsByTag‌​Name("tr")‌
```

Comment: I will debug but I don't think this is correct as this script would also catch the "tr" under "thead" and I said I only want those under "tbody"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS selector:

```
browser.document.querySelectorAll(".mega-table tbody tr")
```

This returns a ***nodeList*** rather than a "collection"; but you can still loop its length.

It says select `tr` tags within `tbody` tag within elements with className (`"."`) of `mega-table`.

[image: CSS query results]

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub IE()

'   Internet Controls Libraray
'   Microsoft HTML Controls Library

Dim I As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim D As HTMLDocument
Dim C As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set I = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

I.Visible = True

I.Navigate ("http://www.stackoverflow.com")

While I.Busy Or I.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Set D = I.Document

Set C = D.getElementsByTagName("TR")


End Sub
```