# Select multiple values in a dropdown listbox on html via VBA

Tags: html, vba, drop-down-menu

**Issue :** Hey, I am trying, from VBA,to select multiple values in a dropdown list on a webpage.

The HTML code of the select element is

[image]

I managed to select this element with `objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0)` since it's the first element with the tagname "select" on the whole webpage.

If I write `objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Value= "E31"`, the value "E31" will be highlighted in the drop box, that's fine.

But how can I select multiple values ?

I tried `objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Value= "E31" + "E32"` or  `objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Value= "E31" & "E32"` but it doesn't work...

EDIT : Further attempts : I am currently trying to fix this issue using the SendKeys command where I click on one element of the list and then select other elements with SendKeys "+{DOWN 4}" which should select the 4 elements in the list under the initial one selected.

```
'objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Children(8).Selected = True' If I activate this line it selects (= highlight) the 9th element of the list
'objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Children(8).Click'if I activate this line it clicks on the 9th element of the list but doesn't highlight it
SendKeys "+{DOWN 3}"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work yet. Moreover, I don't know if there is a way to send a key CTRL + MouseLeftClick somehow as mentioned in [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm) but for the command *Send* which is not valid in VBA.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What have you found via searching? I have found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191847/use-getelementbyid-on-htmlelement-instead-of-htmldocument) within a minute for example. It may be an idea to look into whether JavaScript could be used.

Comment: I only found posts where the person try to select 1 value but not any discussing about how to select mulitple values in a html list coding from VBA. And I don't see the relation with the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :** Ok I found a way to do it, pretty easy actually.

```
With objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")(0)
    .Children(23).Selected = True
    .Children(56).Selected = True
    .Children(98).Selected = True
End With
```

This command will highlight (select) the 3 elements