# click a web element with java script

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I have a web element which is want to click in selenium VBA.

I can do this by selenium vba code shown below but when I do so I get the message "element not clickable at xx,xx point"

`driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[@id='lnkLeaveBackLogEntry']").click`

now I want to click the above element by java script executor. The Relevant html code for above element is

`<a href="#" id="lnkLeaveBackLogEntry" onclick="OpenPartial2(this.id)">Previous Leave Balance</a>`

Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191847/use-getelementbyid-on-htmlelement-instead-of-htmldocument

Comment: I have used following code  `cSCRIPT = "document.getElementById('//a[@id='lnkLeaveBackLogEntry']').click"   
    driver.ExecuteScript cSCRIPT`     but I am getting "javascript error: missing ) after argument"