# How do I get element ID from Object using vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I defined `tdobj as MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement`

I have looped through a webpage and have a `tdobj`.

I am using the below to loop through the page:

```
Dim tds As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim trs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim trObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
Dim tdObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement

Set trs = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

For Each trObj In trs
   Set tds = trObj.getElementsByTagName("td")
   For Each tdObj In tds
      If InStr(1, tdObj.innerText, NameA, 1) > 0 then
         NT = 1
      end if
      If NT > 0 then NT = NT + 1
      if NT = 6 then tdObj.click
   next
next
```

Html of the object is:

```html
<a name="gofo" class="button_link" id="gofo" type="button"
   onclick="javascript:return disableLinks(this.href);" 
   href='javascript:submitLink(document.Form0,"gofo");' 
   renderer="uk.co.cls.tapestry.link.PortalLinkRenderer@2ce745">
      runto
</a>
```

I want to be able to click this particular `tdobj` but `tdObj.FireEvent ("onclick") tdObj.Click` does not work, but does not produce an error message, either.

I was thinking of perhaps obtaining the element ID from the `tdobj` but how do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15192814/11167163)

Comment: You can also use the locals window in your ide to inspect the object.

Comment: No code, no HTML of the elements...  what does `not work` means? Nothing happened? Error?

Comment: ```tdobj.click``` causes nothing to happen. No errors.

Comment: @RaymondWu I have included some more code

Comment: @Stack I don't see click in your code. Can you include the HTML of the target element?

Comment: @RaymondWu I have added more code. Basically I am finding some text in a previous tdobj and counting across. I know I can use the ID of the element but it will not always be the same ID element name. So this is why I want to be able to click the tdObj or get its ID.

Comment: @Stack So if you look at the html of the element, there's a javascript associated with the link and onclick attribute so what you could do (and maybe work,, it depends) is to use `ExecScript` to run the script directly or use `fireEvent` method to trigger the `onclick` attribute. Please google both of these terms and try both methods. You might or might not need to click so please try various combinations.

Comment: @RaymondWu thanks for the pointer - I will try your suggestions and report back.

Comment: @RaymondWu I have tried the below but nothing changed (no error message though) 
                                                                                                               
 ```tdObj.FireEvent ("onclick")
                            tdObj.Click```

Comment: @Stack how about `ExecScript`? I think `javascript:submitLink(document.Form0,"gofo");` is the function you want to execute.

Comment: But how do I get the ```javascript:submitLink(document.Form0,"gofo");``` from the tdObj in the first place?

Comment: @Stack Most likely this function call is fixed so you don't even need to access to tdObj at all, just call the function.